# How to pass parameter to command

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms solution and on one page there is list with images. When image is clicked, I would like to trigger procedure witch has image path as parameter. In xaml I define image with:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
        WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapImageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ImagePath}" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

and TapImageCommand is defined in view model's constructor as:

```cs
TapImageCommand = new Command<string>(ImagePath =>
{
    OnImageTapped(ImagePath);
});
```

and TapImageCommand is defined with:

```cs
public ICommand TapImageCommand { get; set; }
```

Problem is OnImageTapped is never triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint     OnImageTapped(ImagePath); does it stop?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you *think* you are binding the `ImagePath` of the object behind the list, but you are not. Look at the `Command` you are binding, this is part of the PageModel, not the object in the list, so neither is the `CommandParameter`.

Therefore, `ImagePath` is probably `null`, and it does not match the signature you have for the `Command` which expects a `string`.

In this particular case it is probably easiest to supply the whole object as a parameter and get out the property yourself. I will assume the object in the list is of type `Foo`, then edit your code like underneath.

In your view, edit the `TapGestureRecognizer` to this:

`TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapImageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />`

The dot points to itself, in this case the specific instance of `Foo` in your list. Then edit the `Command` like this:

```
TapImageCommand = new Command<Foo>(fooObject =>
{
    OnImageTapped(fooObject);
});
```

Now in your `OnImageTapped` method you can extract the `ImagePath` property.

Comment: I understood the problem you are talking about and tried your implementation, but I'm still unable to trigger the command. Maybe problem is with {Binding .}. I have <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"> and items are defined with <ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><ViewCell>

Comment: solved? I have same issue, I am using MR.gesture plugin for different gestures. In my case, command fired but sometimes command parameter value is null.

Comment: the Command must be of type Command<T> otherwise it will not work

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was looking for selected Index of stack layout or grid and it was done as below.

Command Added as below

```
public ICommand SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<string>((x) => OpenChild(x));
    }
}
public void OpenChild(string x)
{
    //handle parameter x to say "Hello " + x
}
```

Added command on XAML

```
SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource Self}}
```